# Change application window icon for c++ application

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11, visual-studio-2019

So I'm having problems setting the default icon for a c++ graphical application window. I am following a tutorial series on DirectX 11 (found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECOrE1gIAow&list=PLcacUGyBsOIBlGyQQWzp6D1Xn6ZENx9Y2&index=9))

The taskbar icon changes perfectly fine, the executable file that is generated uses the custom icon, but for some reason, the application window doesn't.

According to Microsoft Documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagwndclassexa), there are two HICON properties that I should set values for within the WNDCLASSEX: hIcon and hIconSm; which, according to research can be set with `LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION)` as shown in this example
[LoadIcon](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/578603307887624193/582820745319546900/unknown.png)

I'm not entirely sure the steps that would be taken to reproduce this problem. I don't know if something went wrong when I made the .rc file to load in the .ico image. Or if I loaded the image incorrectly, or... well... some obscure reason that it would only half work.

This is my code for registering the window class that I use to create the window

```cpp
// The window class. This has to be filled BEFORE the window can be WNDCLASSEX wc;
/ Flags [Redraw on width/height change from resize/movement]
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
// Pointer to the window processing function for handling messages from this window
wc.lpfnWndProc = HandleMessageSetup;
// Number of extra bytes to allocate following the window-class structure
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
// Number of extra bytes to allocate following the window instance
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;

// Handle to the instance that contains the window procedure
wc.hInstance = m_hInstance;
// Handle to the class icon. Must be a handle to an Icon resource
wc.hIcon =  LoadIcon(m_hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
// Handle to the small icon for the class
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(m_hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
// Handle to the class cursor. If null, an application must explicitly set the cursor shape whenever the mouse moves into the application window
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
// Handle to the class background brush for the window's background colour. When NULL an application must paint its own background colour
wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
// Pointer to a null-terminated string for the menu
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
// Pointer to null-terminated string of our class name
wc.lpszClassName = m_windowClass.c_str();
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

// Register the class to make it usable
RegisterClassEx(&wc);
```

If more code is needed my repository can be found on [github](https://github.com/intrepid249/DX11_Engine)
(The main class in question is engine/RenderWindow)

According to research, creating a window using CreateWindowEx should then simply work. my taskbar icon changes, however not the application window icon. [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/qxyR5GD)

There are no errors. Code compiles and runs successfully.

Comment: Did you use a debugger to check if the LoadIcons succeeded?

Comment: @HansPassant No I did not ask this question before. There IS, in fact an .rc file in this project. I even stated in my question that I had created a .rc file. I did add some error checking through some of my testing, though it made the code complicated to read and follow, so I reverted to the original code that I had; which according to Microsoft documentation (also linked in my question) SHOULD work correctly.
Does anyone have any useful suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since this still has not been answered, here goes nothing:

*IDI_APPLICATION* refers to the default application icon, it gets set when hIcon is null in the *wc* wndclass.

So here is the jucy part:
IDI_ICON1 is defined in your resource.h file like:

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "icon.ico"
```

Once you have the icon defined you need to turn it into a resource using *MAKEINTRESOURCE*. After which you can use it in the *LoadIcon* function.

*dont forget to include your resource file.*

```
HICON loadedIcon = LoadIcon(wc.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
wc.hIcon = loadedIcon;
wc.hIconSm = loadedIcon;
```

The rest is simillar to your example, you call *RegisterClassEx* and *CreateWindow*